# application Gives me error only on first startup

Tags: android, performance

I get a strange error. base.apk logo appears in something, I have no idea what it is. and why only the first start the application locks a few seconds, and after crashes.
I tried to put

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}

dexOptions {
    incremental false
}
```

In vain, the problem persists and I have no idea why.
Please help.

```
--------- beginning of crash
02-26 21:27:17.087 20016-20016/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming, PID: 20016
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.Permisiuni_index}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.Permisiuni_index" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming-1/lib/arm, /data/app/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.Permisiuni_index" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming-1/lib/arm, /data/app/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.Permisiuni_index" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9_65bec6c0e99615b6ae08811ae3431a58d57b3625-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8_369d87683bcb7ab1ea5edd348f54d1d90cc9cdcd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7_66592a83610dfbb5587cf9c65a89ffe2a67bfe1a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0_8e4446ab2ca4f1db2e259c358dff20c179b01c60-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/data/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
         at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
         at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 12 more
            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.Permisiuni_index
         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                    ... 13 more
      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

build:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionName '2.10.7.Sonia'
        versionCode 11

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}
```

Comment: It says it cant find a class called "ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.Permisiuni_index" Maybe you made a typo?

Comment: if you go a second time everything works perfectly.